# How to dynamically change the period of a repeating Java Runnable?

Tags: java, runnable, minecraft, bukkit

First off, this is Minecraft/Bukkit related, but I believe my problem is not Bukkit specific, just overlooking something small I think (I hope).

At the very bottom of my code is a `randomDelay` and `randomPeriod`. The `run()` function runs repeatedly at a given interval based on these two variables. I don't know how to dynamically change these after the runnable has started. I want to make each period of the runnable vary in length, but the issue is that once the `run()` function has begun, it seems it uses the first values assigned.

```
package code.malon;

import java.util.Random;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitScheduler;

public final class RandomResponse extends JavaPlugin {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int min = 20;
    int max = 200;
    long randomDelay = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    long randomPeriod = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    public void onEnable() {

        BukkitScheduler scheduler = Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler();
        scheduler.scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                randomDelay = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                randomPeriod = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            }
        }, randomDelay, randomPeriod);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to schedule the runnable for a single run, when run, you would schedule it again..

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you, it's so obvious once you say it!

Answer (score 3):

Let's recurse! Oh yeah!

Your code isn't dynamic because you **initialize** the felds when `RandomResponse` is constructed by Bukkit's `PluginClassLoader`. This creates a `new Random()`, generates the random values once and schedules it delaying for the "`randomDelay`". That's not dynamic. Let's fix that with a small hack:

```
public final class RandomResponse extends JavaPlugin {

    final Random rand = new Random();
    final int min = 20;
    final int max = 200;
    // I made these final for arbitrary reasons.

    private RandomResponse randomResponse;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        randomResponse = this; // To use in anonymous class.

        // The delay should be random, so we compute it within onEnable() method.
        // We do not leave it in the class because then it's initialized by constructing.
        long randomDelay = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(this, new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                /*
                 * Stuff to do
                 */
                // Call itself again some time later.
                long randomDelay = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(randomResponse, this, randomDelay);
            }

        }, randomDelay);
    }
}
```

Note that `scheduleSyncRepeatingTask` cannot have the period length of the task changed after it starts running. Hence, you have  to call recursively instead. To allow the task to be cancelled and re-ran, use this:

```
BukkitTask task;

void runTask() {
     cancelTask();
     task = getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(this, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            /*
             * Stuff to do
             */
            // Call itself again some time later.
            long randomDelay = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            task = getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(randomResponse, this, randomDelay);
        }

    }, randomDelay);
}

void cancelTask() {
    if (task != null) try {
        task.cancel();
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
        // Ignore.
    }
}
```

As a side note which may not have occurred to you, you may want to use [`BukkitRunnable`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html) instead of the `Runnable` class from `java.lang`.

Comment: WOW I tried asking this question before and never got a good awnser like this. x_x +1 Well the question is. . . Is this better than letting the bukkitrunnable wait a few iterations more until running task?

Comment: @Lightspeed360 Usually there is no reason to change the period of repeating tasks, I'm only demonstrating how it's done assuming a use case arises. Whether doing it like this is "better" isn't that easily answerable because "it's complicated". However I would advise you establish a functional model for your code beforehand and do that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Set the period to every tick.

```
Task task = new Task();
task.runTaskTimer(Plugin, 1L, 1L);
```

Then use an index and reset it every time the random delay is reached.

```
public class Task extends BukkitRunnable() {
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int index;
    public Task() {
        setRandom();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (index == delay) {
            // Work goes here
            setRandom();
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    private void setRandom() {
        index = random.nextInt(201) + 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not possible to do so with the Bukkit API, you can manage to dynamically update the period of a task with a little help from CraftBukkit and Reflection.

```
public class TaskUtil {
    public static Field CRAFTTASK_PERIOD;

    static {
        try {
            CRAFTTASK_PERIOD = CraftTask.class.getDeclaredField("period");
            CRAFTTASK_PERIOD.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    public static void updateTaskPeriod(int id, long period) {
        CraftScheduler scheduler = (CraftScheduler) Bukkit.getScheduler();
        scheduler.getPendingTasks().forEach(task -> {
            if (task.getTaskId() == id) {
                try {
                    CRAFTTASK_PERIOD.setLong(task, period);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can also take this a step further and eliminate CraftBukkit dependency altogether by utilizing Reflection to get the queued task from the scheduler.